# How can I add sequence of string as column on dataFrame and make as transforms

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a sequence of string

```
val listOfString : Seq[String] = Seq("a","b","c")
```

How can I make a transform like

```
def addColumn(example: Seq[String]): DataFrame => DataFrame {
some code which returns a transform which add these String as column to dataframe
}
input
+-------
| id                      
+-------
|  1     
+-------
output 
+-------+-------+----+-------
| id    |    a  |  b |    c                   
+-------+-------+----+-------
|  1    |  0    |  0 |    0     
+-------+-------+----+-------
```

I am only interested in making it as transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `transform` method of the datasets together with a single `select` statement:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

def addColumns(extraCols: Seq[String])(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val selectCols = df.columns.map{col(_)} ++ extraCols.map{c => lit(0).as(c)}
  df.select(selectCols :_*)
}


// usage example
val yourExtraColumns : Seq[String] = Seq("a","b","c")

df.transform(addColumns(yourExtraColumns))
```

**Resources**

https://towardsdatascience.com/dataframe-transform-spark-function-composition-eb8ec296c108

https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/chaining-custom-dataframe-transformations/

Comment: thanks for posting but Can you make an intermediate function having datatype as DataFrame => DataFrame . The reason is that In my code i am having List[DataFrame => DataFrame] as a function

Comment: the above function you can also write it as `def addColumns(extraCols: Seq[String]): DataFrame => DataFrame = {
  val selectCols = df.columns.map{col(_)} ++ extraCols.map{c => lit(0).as(c)}
  df => df.select(selectCols :_*)
}` this is what you mean? It is the same as above but different declaration type in Scala

Answer (score 1):

Use **`.toDF()`** and pass your **listOfString**.

**`Example:`**

```
//sample dataframe
df.show()
//+---+---+---+
//| _1| _2| _3|
//+---+---+---+
//|  0|  0|  0|
//+---+---+---+


df.toDF(listOfString:_*).show()
//+---+---+---+
//|  a|  b|  c|
//+---+---+---+
//|  0|  0|  0|
//+---+---+---+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

Use **`foldLeft`** to add the **columns** to the existing **dataframe** with values.

```
val df=Seq(("1")).toDF("id")

val listOfString : Seq[String] = Seq("a","b","c")

val new_df=listOfString.foldLeft(df){(df,colName) => df.withColumn(colName,lit("0"))}
//+---+---+---+---+
//| id|  a|  b|  c|
//+---+---+---+---+
//|  1|  0|  0|  0|
//+---+---+---+---+

//or creating a function 
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def addColumns(extraCols: Seq[String],df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val new_df=extraCols.foldLeft(df){(df,colName) => df.withColumn(colName,lit("0"))}
  return new_df
}

addColumns(listOfString,df).show()
//+---+---+---+---+
//| id|  a|  b|  c|
//+---+---+---+---+
//|  1|  0|  0|  0|
//+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I want to make a transfrom of type DataFrame => DataFrame

Comment: @AdityaSeth,Use `toDF()` on the `existing DataFrame` and new dataframe will have new column names!

Comment: How you are initializing the value like I mean by default value

Comment: @AdityaSeth, Check my Updated answer by using `foldLeft` to add the columns.

Comment: thanks for posting but Can you make an intermediate function having datatype as DataFrame => DataFrame . The reason is that In my code i am having List[DataFrame => DataFrame] as a function

Comment: Can you answer this question as I am new to scala  please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61625519/how-to-update-column-value-for-a-particular-row