# How to update column value for a particular row randomly by using column name

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
def getSequence(row : Row) : Seq[String] = {
some code
}
```

Basically I want to iterate the dataFrame by row and update the value with 1 for the sequence I get from getSequence.

Input

```
+---+----+-----+
|sno|dept|color|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|  0 |  0  |
|  2|  0 |  0  |
|  3|  0 |  0  |
+---+----+-----+

getSequence for Row 1 give Seq("dept")
Row 2 give Seq("color") Row 3 give Seq("dept","color")
output be like 
+---+----+-----+
|sno|dept|color|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|  1 |  0  |
|  2|  0 |  1  |
|  3|  1 |  1  |
+---+----+-----+
```

Comment: You can do foreach on Dataframe, but you loose the benefits of Spark. Instead get a DF of all mapping values and do the join

Comment: @skjagini can you write code to iterate and update as I am not familiar with it .

Comment: I have written the code by taking Row agruments

Comment: I saw your final output , You are just updating randomly. Do you have any pattern update only these columns & only in this row when this condition match ?

Comment: Like there is no pattern , only I know the column name to be updated

Comment: So it this possible or not @Srinivas

Comment: Yes, Its possible. Whatever I understood from your question I have added answer below, If it is wrong let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`def lit(literal: Any): org.apache.spark.sql.Column`

`def monotonically_increasing_id(): org.apache.spark.sql.Column`

Use `lit` function to update column values.

Please check below code to update specific column.

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,0,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,0)).toDF("sno","dept","color").withColumn("id",monotonically_increasing_id)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sno: int, dept: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.withColumn("dept",when($"id" =!= 1,lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))).withColumn("color",when($"id" =!= 0,lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))).drop("id").show(false)
+---+----+-----+
|sno|dept|color|
+---+----+-----+
|1  |1   |0    |
|2  |0   |1    |
|3  |1   |1    |
+---+----+-----+
```

Comment: I think u got me wrong , basicaaly I have to iterate each row and using the getSequence function I will get Sequence of columns which should be updated

Comment: Can you give me some info what actual you are going to do inside getSequence method & also why are you taking row as method input ?

Comment: Basicaaly I have put some conditions which will give me those column sequence to be updated.

Comment: I just want to know can I iterate each row and calculate the sequence of column and then append their value ?

Comment: ok, just trying to understand your requirement, can you give some example condition inside that method ?

Comment: I understand your method is returning Seq of column names, I want details on what condition you are returning Seq of columns ?

Comment: Basically based on that condition I can aslo make a new function but I want to reuse that  function

Comment: for iterating you can use map method & pass your function
something like df.map(getSequence), but if you are returning column names it will not working instead update column values inside your method & return row back.